# My legal domain name is not a legal Java package name

Tags: java, package

The name of my domain name is 3DTOPO.com. Apparently java does not allow package domain names to start with a number.

Why doesn't the Java reverse domain name follow the same rules as domain names do? I really don't want to name my package com.threedtopo....

For starters that isn't my domain name! Anyone else would be free to register and use that domain. Besides it is very awkward and not the name of my business.

Does anyone have package name suggestions?

Comment: "Apparently java does not allow domain names to start with a number." => what? Do you have some code?

Comment: Are you mixing the terms "package" and "domain name" up?

Comment: Why do you feel such a strong urge to sync your domain name and your package names?  What's wrong with _com.tdt_ as a package prefix (3 starts with a t).  I'd be WAY more concerned about using _short_ package names (rather than ones that match the legal name of my organization).

Comment: jahroy: I thought the whole concept of using reverse domain names was minimize conflicts. What if Tucker Davis Technologies develops an app and uses their reverse domain name?

Comment: Every company I've ever worked for has used an outdated, out of sync acronym for their package names.  Nowadays company names seem to come and go (as companies are bought, sold, and re-named).  I've never been a part of an effort to re-factor package names just because the company name changed...

Comment: @jahroy Because that would confuse Tucker-Davis Technologies' Java devs, and irritate Maven users when they both released stuff with the same group id? I don't see why *you're* so adamant about not caring; you seem even more upset than the OP.

Comment: @jahroy As a point of information, btw, I *have* worked at places where packages were renamed when the company name changed, along with copyright headers, and so on. Several places, in fact.

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad I've never worked at a place like that!  And hopefully re-factoring tools made it a trivial operation.  If you ever get to worry about such things with your code, you're probably a lucky guy!

Comment: @jahroy So are they. "Was that class on the old or new packages?" Yuck, no thanks. Consistency is actually useful.

Comment: @jahroy Also, if you don't use an @, the person you're replying to may not be notified you're talking to them, depending on context.

Comment: @DaveNewton -  Um... thanks for making my point for me.  That's why there's no point re-naming packages just because a company changed its name:  Just keep things consistent by continuing to use the original package name.  (Not sure why I seem upset)

Comment: Um... whatever. It's not consistent to keep using a package name that isn't your company any more. Less so if someone else buys the rights to the old name, or... etc. There can also be legal (internal and external) ramifications, client implications both technical and otherwise, and so on. Laugh and point all you want, but the reality is that there are several good reasons to migrate package names, and it's not a big deal.

Comment: Your points are valid for sure.  Maybe I'm being to snarky, but my main point was that A.) there's not an unbreakable rule that your package name matches your domain name and B.) The OP _probably_ doesn't have to worry about any of this for quite some time.

Comment: @jahroy - A) You are right.  The advice about using reverse DNS names as the package prefix is **advice**.  But it is **good advice**, because ... B) The problem with people ignoring the advice is that it can cause trouble *at some future point*.  For instance, imagine (hypothetically) that Microsoft decided to unilaterally start publishing lots of stuff in the "desktop" package.  Q: who gets hurt?  A: potentially anyone who ignored the advice and used "desktop" as their package prefix.  *"Microsoft - he don't care!"* Moral: ignore the advice at your peril.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [RFC 1912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#page-2),

> Allowable characters in a label for a host name are only ASCII
> letters, digits, and the `-' character.  Labels may not be all
> numbers, but may have a leading digit  (e.g., 3com.com).  Labels must
> end and begin only with a letter or digit.  See [RFC 1035] and [RFC
> 1123].  (Labels were initially restricted in [RFC 1035] to start with
> a letter, and some older hosts still reportedly have problems with
> the relaxation in [RFC 1123].)  Note there are some Internet
> hostnames which violate this rule (411.org, 1776.com).  The presence
> of underscores in a label is allowed in [RFC 1033], except [RFC 1033]
> is informational only and was not defining a standard.  There is at
> least one popular TCP/IP implementation which currently refuses to
> talk to hosts named with underscores in them.  It must be noted that
> the language in [1035] is such that these rules are voluntary -- they
> are there for those who wish to minimize problems.  Note that the
> rules for Internet host names also apply to hosts and addresses used
> in SMTP (See RFC 821).

So the allowing digits at the front of domain names didn't begin until [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#section-2), in 1989.

It's worth noting that they started writing Java in 1990. Domains beginning with numbers probably weren't common by then, so package names seemed analogous to hostnames.

Package names don't have to directly correspond to domain names. To me, domain names are temporary - they can be bought and sold. Package names might last much longer than domain names.

For what it's worth, 3com solved it by buying another domain. ;-) They used `com.palm.webos`  for some software.

Comment: And now that there's Unicode domain names (and the mind-boggling [rfc5892](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5892)) it gets even more confusing :/

Answer (score 11):

I think you mean Java doesn't allow package names to begin with a number.

One common alternative is to preface it with an underscore, _3dtopo.

Comment: Java doesn't allow *any symbolic name* to begin with a number.

Comment: That is the only thing I can think of, but still makes me cringe. If they chose to base packages on domain names, why don't they allow legal domain names to be used?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock, package names can be used as symbolic names anywhere within your program. If you had a package named `3L`, the parser wouldn't know if that was the number `3` (long) or your package name.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Parsing/lexing simplification/normalization. Plus when Java was invented there weren't very many domain names. Of all the things to complain about regarding Java, this is pretty low on my list.

Comment: Actually, it's a vast conspiracy with the sellers of domain names. They want you to pay another 15 bucks to buy another package name. The nerve!

Comment: @PeterGluck Correct, but I was specifically correcting the OP's statement.

Comment: You know... as I read the BNF in [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt), DNS originally didn't allow a digit in the first position of a domain name. Extract: `<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]`

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I thought not, but couldn't remember that far back. Ugh, just flashed back to bang-paths, too.

Comment: Alas, starting with an underscore does not appear to be a valid solution. It compiles with no errors, but when I try to install the apk I get this error: 10-10 20:49:49.740: E/PackageParser(15789): parsePackageLite error: <manifest> specifies bad package name "com._3dtopo.comicbook.android": bad character '_'

Comment: ARRRRR! Even worse, even the APK won't install, Google won't let me upload a new APK with a different reverse domain name. So looks like the hours I spent setting up my Google Play page are completely wasted. I am under a deadline, and I don't think I will have time to create a new listing. In other words I am pretty much screwed.

Answer (score 10):

Sun/Oracle specifically addresses this question in the Java tutorial's [Naming a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) section:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int". In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore.

They proceed to give a few examples, the relevant one in this case being the domain `123name.example.com` becoming package `com.example._123name`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't the Java reverse domain name follow the same rules as domain names do?

Because:

1. It isn't a 'reverse domain name', it is a Java package name.
2. It is composed of Java identifiers, which don't permit a leading digit.